# Codeigniter to develop Android App

Tags: android, codeigniter

I have made a website in Codeigniter which is pretty complex and now I need to make an Android App for the same. Is there a way to do this without recoding?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create an android app same as your website without recoding the answer is no.

But if you only want display your website in your application yes, you can use webview to display the website but I don't think that'll be a good user experience for the user of your app.

But hey why you don't want recode? coding is fun isn't it? :p

Comment: Would I have to recode the front-end or back-end code? Or both? Coding is definitely fun when you have time ;-)

Comment: @rohitnaidu19 yes the time is the biggest problem :D, you only need to add some code to the backend no need to modify the front-end website, to create API to create a way for your android application to access data from your server :)